# Contour Plot command

Tags: untagged

If we have three independent variables , how can I fix the value of one variable and giving the range for two others in the contour plot command? I have mass of one Dark matter particle and then the mass of the other dark matter particle and the portal coupling as a third variable, how can I plot them in Mathematica software?

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for StackOverflow as it is more of a programming question and not related to physics per se.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please include Mathematica code for your expression in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a function of 3 variables and want to fix the value of one variable and make a plot of the other 2 variables. here is an example:

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1 x2 x3;
Plot3D[f[1, x2, x3], {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Works also with ContourPlot as requested...